# Нахождение прямоугольных треугольников

Tags: c++, математика, геометрия

WinForms c++ задача:

> Напишите программу, которая находит все прямоугольные треугольники (длины сторон выражаются натуральными числами), площадь которых не превышает данного числа S.

Сложность в написании алгоритма нахождения прямоугольного треугольника, перебор всех чисел подряд видимо является неверным.
Не понимаю как реализовать данный цикл?

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;

    int s, k;
    s = Convert::ToInt64(textBox1->Text);
    k = 0;// количество прямоугольных треугольников
    for (int a = 1; a <= 100; a++) {
        for (int b = 1; b <= 100; b++) {
            if (0.5 * a * b < s) {
                k++; // если площадь не превышает S, увеличиваем k на 1
            }
        }
    }


    textBox2->Text = Convert::ToString(k) // выводим k


}
```

Comment: Целыми должны быть все три стороны треугольника? Или только катеты?

Comment: @Harry все три стороны должны быть целыми

Comment: Тогда просто рассматривайте все [пифагоровы тройки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0), проверяя соответствующие пары (m,n), с учетом того, что `(m^2-n^2)mn <= S`.

Comment: Да, спасибо, я разобрался

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот, на коленке писанный, без малейших попыток оптимизации код для поиска всех треугольников с площадью до заданной.

```
unsigned int S;
cin >> S;

for(unsigned int n = 1;n*(n+1)*(2*n+1) <= S;++n)
{
    for(unsigned int m = n+1; (m*m-n*n)*m*n<=S; ++m)
    {
        if (m%2 == n%2 || gcd(m,n) > 1) continue;
        unsigned int a = m*m - n*n;
        unsigned int b = 2*m*n;
        unsigned int c = m*m+n*n;
        unsigned int s = a*b/2;
        for(unsigned int k = 1; s*k*k <= S; ++k)
            cout
                << setw(4) << k*a << "  "
                << setw(4) << k*b << "  "
                << setw(4) << k*c << "   "
                << setw(4) << k*k*s << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Можно ли gcd чем либо заменить? Vs не поддерживает его

Comment: Как раз VC++ 2017 его вполне поддерживает. Ну, напишите сами - это ж 2 строчки...

Comment: А можете обьяснить, что делают эти строчки? 
for(unsigned int n = 1;n*(n+1)*(2*n+1) <= S;++n)
{
    for(unsigned int m = n+1; (m*m-n*n)*m*n<=S; ++m)
Для чего они и что находят?

Comment: Просто цикл по всем возможным вариантам. В заголовке цикла - максимальное значение n, при котором может не быть превышена площадь; ниже, во втором цикле - вторая проверка, теперь уже на m.

Comment: А откуда берется n*(n + 1)*(2 * n + 1)?

Comment: При максимальном n m должно быть минимально, т.е. не более n+1. Подставляем, проверяем...